# Issue using bash/xlsx2csv to iterate through files converting from XLS to CSV

Tags: python, linux, bash, csv

I am attempting to iterate through XLS files and convert them to CSV using XLSX2CSV. Oddly, my script below is working locally but I get this error performing the script on live server.

**Bash Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=public/uploads/imports/*.xlsx
for f in $FILES
do
filename=$(basename "$f" .xlsx)
outext=".csv" 
file="public/uploads/imports/"$filename$outext
echo "Processing $file file..."
xlsx2csv "$f" > "${file%.}"
done

mv public/uploads/imports/*.xlsx public/uploads/imports/processed
echo "Moved Files to Processed Folder"
```

**Error**

```
IndexError: list index out of range
Processing public/uploads/imports/fbb8099038b2f56269fe301e927e7685.csv file...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xlsx2csv", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('xlsx2csv==0.7.6', 'xlsx2csv')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 540, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1462, in run_script
    exec_(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 41, in exec_
    exec("""exec code in globs, locs""")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsx2csv-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/xlsx2csv", line 1124, in <module>

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsx2csv-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/xlsx2csv", line 198, in __init__

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It looks like this error is being generated by the python. Is this the same version of xls2csv? Are you testing locally with the same files, or an example file that fails?

Comment: Python (Local: 2.7.17) (Server: 2.7.5) - XLSX2CSV (Local: 0.7.2) (Server: 0.7.6) - I am using the same files on both server and local.

Answer (score 1):

I was using a newer version of xlsx2csv 0.7.6 and when downgraded to 0.7.2 worked perfectly.